# Trying to read XML nodes using PHP DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm trying to read the relevant nodes in the following XML string, to finally display:

> flerror:0
>
> Message from directory:Pings being
>   forwarded to 11 services!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
  <member><name>flerror</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member>
  <member><name>message</name><value><string>Pings being forwarded to 11 services!</string></value></member>
</struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodResponse>
```

I tried using:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xmlString);
$value = $doc->getElementsByTagName("value");
$value = $value->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

and obtained:

```
<br>flerror0<br>
  messagePings being forwarded to 11 services!
```

I can then use string parsing functions to separate out the strings, but that I need a cleaner solution.

Any suggested improvements that will possibly avoid the additional string parsing?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code works for me: http://codepad.org/aximvvBG. `nodeValue` will give you the combined DOMTextNode values of the element it is fetched for. If you want separate nodeValues, fetch separate nodes and format the output with `sprintf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not much experience with `DOMDocument`. But looks like your xml is small and simple, I would suggest to use [simple xml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). Here is what I have wrote

```
<?php
$xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
  <member><name>flerror</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member>
  <member><name>message</name><value><string>Pings being forwarded to 11 services!</string></value></member>
</struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodResponse>
";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml->params->param->value);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

And got

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [struct] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [member] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => flerror
                            [value] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [boolean] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => message
                            [value] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [string] => Pings being forwarded to 11 services!
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I think now it will be much easier to access every node.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with DOMDocument, and it seems that it's not able to give content from a node named "param"...

Try changing the name to "parameter", it will work

True story